# BigQuery access, security and cost controls?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm totally new to BQ and learning as much as I can. I'm not sure how access and cost controls work if I create a multi-tenant environment.

Here's my use case, I have different clients who are sending me data and I'm providing analytics on. My thought was to accept this via a API/cloudrun-->pubsub-->dataflow/my analytics-->BQ

Within BQ, for each client, I was going to create a dataset and tables so the different clients' data is separated. But I was thinking maybe there's more I need to do, is there a better way to secure each dataset for each client? Also can I enforce limits on each dataset so if there are too many reports being run by a specific client then I can manage my budgets?

Lastly, I'm totally new to BQ so if there are other considerations I should be thinking about I would appreciate any feedback.

Edit - just to clarify, I have seen access controls for IAM but these clients do not have direct IAM accounts, they have logical accounts on our platform(firebase and our own table with user attributes), so I'm not sure to restrict access other than via app logic but I might be missing something here.

Comment: I think I'm sensing that the caller making the BQ calls is from a service account and hence all requests are going to appear to come from a consistent/constant identity.  If that's the case, I don't see that BQ has any information to work upon to constrain requests at the platform layer.  This means that a mistake in coding/logic could expose data.  If each request was from a unique identity, then IAM would come into play.  This would include constraining requests by quota by identity.

Comment: @Kolban yes you are the right. The requests come from the same identify (our app).  The users aren’t in iam but in firebase. 

I had a chat with another googler on Reddit and I don’t believe it’s possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all your requirement, I strongly recommend to create 1 project per customer. You have may advantages to that design:

- The cost is easier per project and you can have it per customer
- On BigQuery, you can set quotas to limit the cost per project only (not per dataset)
- You can use IAM as you use it today in a single project.

About IAM, your customer haven't a Google Account and you can't use IAM with them. In that case, you have to grand your API endpoint solution the permission to access to BigQuery (in all the project that you create) and to handle manually to which project a customer can request.

I recommend to log that routing to have the capacity to audit what happens in case of issue or misconfiguration.

Comment: That you so much Guillaume! My challenge here is we hope to scale without manual intervention. If we are targeting 10k customers, would there be any negative impact of creating 10k projects?

Comment: Also, another concern with the suggested approach is some customers will want not to share compute(which for whom we will create instances for them), but for those we want to share, I'm not sure if designing projects will be cost-efficient.

Comment: Create 10k project, why not. You have quotas not to create them too fast but there is no issue to that design. However, I didn't understand your "share compute" design. There is no compute here, only serverless product. Not sure to follow you.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know there was no restrictions on the projects. Thank you.

Sorry, my mistake. It's been a long week and I confused the tech stacks. When I asked this I was thinking of using BQ at my datastore but since then I was advised that exposing BQ to end users could cause my costs to explode so I was looking at spanner. With Spanner we share compute(1 node per 2 tb), I mixed the questions up. Thank you and sorry for confusing you.

Comment: but now I'm rethinking BQ design. If I can enforce quotas on a project level then no single user could blow up our costs. Something new for me to consider. Thank you.